# How to correct Error to use generic LinkedList in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I'm using LinkedList with generic types and get this error,

```
error: type LinkedList does not take parameters
Queue<Node> list = new LinkedList<Node>();
```

I have `Node class` with simple constructor and some methods that I can provide if required. The import is corrected and as following,

```
import java.util.*;
```

I have a method where I have initiated the LinkedList object as following,

```
public static boolean searchNode(Graph graph, Node start, Node end){

     Queue<Node> list = new LinkedList<Node>();
}
```

What's the issue here  and why do I get error ? I use Java 8 for compiling.

Comment: Can you share the `import` statement for the `LinkedList<Node>`?

Comment: which IDE are you using? Also, can you try to import full class instead.

Comment: Use this instead

import java.util.List;

Comment: I had some compiled classes in the same directory and I deleted them. The problem is solved immediately. Omer @ I use Sublime text for coding.